# sleep(seconds) in wasm keeps CPU usage high

Tags: sleep, webassembly, web-worker

My wasm code has a call to [POSIX sleep(seconds)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) function. This call is done for limiting CPU consumption but I notice no difference with or without sleep, either with 1 or 1000 seconds.

My code initially had this structure

```c
void myfunc(u32 *buff){
    
        u32 size = 16;
        while (1){
    
            for (u32 i = 0; i < size; i++){
                // do stuff
            }
        }
}
```

myfunc() si called by a Web Worker raising the CPU usage from 3% to 28% and when I terminate() the Web Worker the CPU drops down to 3%.

So I added a limiter to mitigate the CPU usage and keep it lower

```c
#include <unistd.h>
void myfunc(u32 *buff){
    
        u32 size = 16;
        while (1){
            sleep(1); // 1s or 1000s same behavior
    
            for (u32 i = 0; i < size; i++){
                // do stuff
            }
        }
}
```

but this change has no effect on CPU usage I only see that the sleep works and the thread is suspended for the time requested.

The for cycle takes a fraction of second so the time spent in sleeping is greater than the time spent in running.

I would add that when I do my tests I have no others CPU-intensive processes running hence I would expect a lower CPU usage when sleep(1000) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This only points that your environment uses a loop to implement the sleep function (you could probably verify that with a debugger).

If the stack-switching proposal was ready, merged, and implemented in your environment, probably some `await` for a promise would be used, but the stack-switching is [not ready yet](https://github.com/WebAssembly/stack-switching).